# Content-disposition for directories

Tags: nginx

It is possible to force download files on nginx server so instead of a user going through a directory listing, they could click on a directory hosted on the server and the directory will be downloaded as a whole. I have tried something like:

```
add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment';
```

but it does not work. Can someone take a look at this. I have read lots of sources for force downloading files like pdf or png or jpg, but none do this for a whole directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have just thought of a solution. It does not download a directory, but what I did is I compressed the directory and then added this:

```
    location ~ ^.*/(?P<request_basename>[^/]+\.(zip))$ {
        root /dir/to/zipfile/;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$request_basename"';
}
```

into nginx and it works.